# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object dataLayer.php on line 39

Tags: php, database, pdo

This code is in my class `Testing`.

```
class Testing {
    // irrelevant code

     private $dbh; 

     function connect(){
        try{
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=database", "username", "password");
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            print "Connected to MYSQL<br/><br/>";
            return true;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    function setData($sql){
        try{
            $stmt = $dbh->query($sql); // Line 39
            if($stmt == null){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true; 
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    function getData($sql){
        if(!setData($sql)){
            print "SQL statment is null<br/><br/>";
        }
        else{
            try{
                foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
                    # code...
                    print "<p>".$row['fName']. ' '. $row['lName']. ' ' .$row['email']. "</p>";
                }
            }
            catch(PDOException $Exception){
                $Exception->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    // more irrelevant code

}
```

And then I call getData() in index.php:

```
<?php
    require_once "dataLayer.php";
    $x = new Testing(); 
    $x-> connect();
    $x->getData("SELECT * FROM faculty");
?>
```

Any idea what's wrong with this code? Is there something wrong with syntax?

Comment: Is this code perhaps living inside a class?

Comment: Where (which file) have you defined your functions? And where are you calling it from (which file)?

Comment: Deceze, yes this code is inside a class.

Comment: @Havelock, I added codes in other file that you asked me.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see where the problem is. It occurs when you're calling `setData()` in the `getData()`.
Since you defined `setData()` as a method of the same class you should be calling it as such from inside the class. So change

```
function getData($sql){
    if(!setData($sql)){
```

to

```
function getData($sql){
    if(!$this->setData($sql)){
```

Note: for the future please post the complete error message (including line number) and mark the line on which the error occurs (see my edit of your post), as well as just a little bit of (relevant) code that would have suggested those functions are defined as class methods.

Comment: thank you, and it works however I got another error message, it said, "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /Volumes/Students/students/135/pju2173/Sites/DB_PDO/dataLayer.php on line 37"

Comment: In case that the `$dbh` variable has been set in the constructor or another method (?) then you probably should be using `$this->dbh` instead of `$dbh`. Just a wild guess...